# Why can’t Mario enter the pipe for A Traditional Festival?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I’m playing Super Mario Odyssey and have beaten Bowser, and am now returning to the various kingdoms. I left Metro Kingdom after unlocking the band since I could not enter the pipe for the Festival.

Returning, I still cannot enter. I leave Mario’s ship, enter the pipe on the platform that enters a 2D area with a pipe directly above. In all YouTube walkthroughs, players simply jump to enter the pipe above. However, when I jump, it acts as a barrier: I cannot enter.

You can see the section at 27:00 in this YouTube video:

Here is a screenshot from that video showing Mario jumping, about to enter the pipe above his head. It’s this pipe I can’t get into.

[image]

I have tried:

- Jumping in many ways - the Y button, flicking the controller, moving around the small 2D area
- Wearing the pinstripe suit and hat, in case it was a prerequisite for entering this stage of New Donk City

I have version 1.0.1. Running software update tells me there are no updates.

Comment: You're holding up on the joystick when you make contact, right?

Comment: Nope. I always press ZL to enter a pipe... and it turns out that doesn’t work on ceiling pipes. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When Mario is standing on top of a tube, you need to press **down** to go **down** the tube (in 3D mode you need to crouch instead).

In this case, it's the other way around: To go **up** the tube, you need to press **up**. This obviously only works if Mario is in contact with the tube, that's where the jumping comes in.

So in short:

1. Jump towards the pipe, as seen in the video you're linking.
2. Make sure you are pressing **up** when you make contact with the pipe.

Luckily, this doesn't involve any timing at all, so you can simply keep the analog stick pressed upwards while you jump. If Mario doesn't climb up the pipe, try moving him a bit more towards the center of the pipe.

Comment: That’s it! To enter a pipe you can move the control stick down, or press ZL. But to enter a pipe above you can only move the control stick. And I always press ZL.

Answer (score 1):

Hold up on the joystick, there are several other 8 bit mini games that have an upward tube. (There's one on the moon)